# Regarding removing spaces between terms in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions

I have been generating some mathematical expressions using FORM (symbolic manipulation system). The expression I get then needs to be passed to Mathematica for further analysis.

The problem I get is basically this: when I simply copy the output and then paste it from FORM to Mathematica, I do get spaces between terms (like I get some red color on mathematical operations - addition, subtraction etc. - and/or the variables I defined).

What I do then is basically use a brute force and remove all these spaces between terms and continue the analysis. However, as you might guess this is a cumbersome process and time consuming for very long expressions.

I would like to now if you know some trick to save some time. I do remember that there was a trick that I used to do but unfortunately I can't recall it right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try pasting the FORM output into a plain text editor first, then copy it from there to Mathematica.  That might clean it up.  Otherwise try posting some sample data with your question, for people to work with.

Comment: extra spaces would not be an issue for mathematica, you must be getting something other than ordinary ascii spaces. maybe try here http://www.nikhef.nl/~form/forum/

Comment: If you could edit your post to show one or two specific examples of exactly what you are doing, what you are getting and what you would want instead then someone might be able to provide a solution. If I try to read this "when I simply copy the output and then paste it from FROM to Mathematica I do get spaces" (read that a single word at a time) it is really difficult for me to be absolutely certain exactly what you did and what you want instead. Imagine someone on the other side of the world trying to guess how to give you exactly the right answer on the first try. Thank you